# Unable to update Ubuntu on VM

Tags: apt, updates, virtualbox, linux-headers, 22.04

This is a screenshot of the `404 Not Found` error messages I'm getting when trying to update Ubuntu 22.04 on a virtual machine:

[image: Img]

Comment: Your output says `404 Not Found`. Do you understand what that means? Or is that what you are asking?

Comment: I ask how to fix it. Is there a command I should run?

Comment: Do other network applications in your VM have connectivity?

Comment: Yes, I run Firefox and it loads all pages

Comment: Then your mirror is down. It happens. Either be patient until it comes back up, or select a different mirror.

Comment: Please copy text from the terminal and paste in your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer you question? [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/q/65911/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help. There were only 2 ways. Either wait till mirror works fine again, or using different one.